# Progress bar in popup with kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want a progress bar in popup, that show popup while add extra widgets to the layout, I tried to do it by using tread, creating two tasks one for progress bar another for adding widgets but it is not working as I thought.

I can't share whole code because it is too long.

I need a popup while adding widgets that enough to do my other work.

```
class FileUploadWindow(Widget):
    def choose_file(self):
        file = easygui.fileopenbox(default="*.csv")
        self.ids.heading.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.grid.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.index.clear_widgets()
        if file is not None:
            self.ids.location.text = file
            self.file = file.replace('\\', '\\\\')
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.progress, name='t1')
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.update_layout, args=[file], name='t2')

            t1.start()
            t2.start()

            t1.join()
            t2.join()

    def update_layout(self, file):
        dataf = pd.read_csv(file)
        real = dataf.pop("DEATH_EVENT")
        self.ids.heading.add_widget(RecordLabel(text="DEATH_EVENT(p)"))
        self.ids.heading.add_widget(RecordLabel(text="Compare"))

        for col in list(dataf.columns):
            self.ids.heading.add_widget(RecordLabel(text=col))
        model = ModelLoading()
        predict = model.multipleRecords(dataf[["age",
                                               "creatinine_phosphokinase",
                                               "ejection_fraction",
                                               "serum_creatinine",
                                               "time"]])
        for i in range(dataf.shape[0]):
            self.ids.index.add_widget(IndexLabel(text=str(i + 1)))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(RecordLabel(text=str(predict[i])))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(RecordLabel(text=str(predict[i] == real[i])))
            for j in dataf.columns:
                self.ids.grid.add_widget(RecordLabel(text=str(dataf[j][i])))

    def progress(self):
        progress = MyPopup()
        progress.open()
```